# SignInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync coming null when calling from angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, session-cookies

I am using AspNetCoreIdentity with two factor authentication in my .Net 6 web api.

I do this on login api

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
var signResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginModel.Password, false, true);

if (signResult.RequiresTwoFactor)
{
    if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginModel.Password))
    {
        var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);

        var message = new MessageDto(new string[] { user.Email! }, "OTP Confrimation", token);
        _emailService.SendEmail(message);

        return BuildResponse<LoginResponseDto>();
    }
    else
    {
        return BuildFailureResponse<LoginResponseDto>("Login failed. Wrong password!");
    }
}
```

Then on two factor api I try to load user like this

```
var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
```

Everything works perfectly when I check it from Swagger.

I successfully get user from `SignInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync` method call but when I call the same api's from my angular front end the first login happens successfully but on two factor method `SignInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync` starts giving me `null`.

Any idea what could be going wrong when I try it from angular?

Since it is not finding the user so I assume that either the cookie is not set properly during this call of login method

```
var signResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginModel.Password, false, true);
```

Or the cookie is set properly but somehow it is not able to connect the current user with this cookie.

Do we need to do some setting in the front end for it to make server know which cookie to user?